# Sortable results for a horizontal accordioned table grid

Tags: jquery, sorting, horizontal-accordion

I have an accordion grid script that I've been working on for some time now. The whole concept behind it is to offer groups of columns that are expandable/collapsible by category (horizontally) to help reduce horizontal scrolling in the browser.

The problem I'm encountering now is that because the script is breaking up the data by category (the code returns all rows of data for a given category, closes tables and lists, then moves on to next category), I'm having a really hard time wrapping my head around how to make everything sortable.

I need this script to function is a way where the user can click on any given category or column heading to sort all rows by the clicked category or column heading.

**[I've created a demo version of my script to help show people how the code is structured for the grid.](http://redapplefalls.net/_projects/expand-test/demo.html)** It's kind of difficult to explain otherwise.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: concept is nice. but the question looks more towards DB. are you looking on click jquery ajax sort

Comment: Yeah, I've been thinking this should be sortable on the back-end too but unfortunately, the data results will potentially be enormous. It would be too heavy of a load on the server. I need to figure out some way to do this strictly front-end. *I keep thinking this should be resolvable somewhere between the front and back-end.. in that foggy middlewhere...

Comment: then it more towards db, yu should not bring all the data at once. if yu showing only 10 records bring 10. so on each click ajax call willbring data what is  needed.

Comment: You mean pull the data in by category? There is no planned pagination for this script. If I get it working, it will be used for an online reporting tool. Even if we use a separate call for each category, I think the data sets could still be huge depending. I'll have to check with my back-end dev guys to be sure though.

Comment: One thing that *might* make this all workable would be if the rows between each category's data could be uniquely identified maybe? My js/jquery skills are not the strongest..

Comment: In SO if yu want to get answer you have to post what youd did and where you stuck..post some code and say you have issue here..btb the data is huge means .. yu need pagination is it